# Is it possible to have Getter/Setter in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've just learnt about Getters/Setters for objects and decided to play with it. However, I tried to put a Getter in an array and failed to do so. Is it not possible or am I just doing something wrong?

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  get b() { return this.a + 1 } 
}

console.log(obj.b) //2
```

**For Array**

```
const arr = [
  1,
  get () { return this[0] + 1 } 
]

console.log(arr[1]) // Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it not possible or am I just doing something wrong?

It's not possible using an array initializer (loosely, an "array literal").

You could define an accessor property after the fact, though, via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
const arr = [1];
Object.defineProperty(arr, "1", {
  get() {
    return this[0] + 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr[1]); // 2
```

You can combine that, I've left the steps above separate for clarity, but `Object.defineProperty` returns the object you call it on, so:

```js
const arr = Object.defineProperty([1], "1", {
  get() {
    return this[0] + 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr[1]); // 2
```

**I wouldn't**, but you can. :-) Why wouldn't I? Because arrays expect their properties with array index names¹ to be simple data properties, not accessors, and so various array methods (like `splice`) will fail if they try to set the `"1"` property to a different value (you could fix that by adding a setter). In general, though, I'd leave array entry properties alone.

That said, if the property has both a getter and a setter, I can't *immediately* think of a problem with it. Here's the above with a setter, just for completeness:

```js
const arr = Object.defineProperty([1], "1", {
  get() {
    return this[0] + 1;
  },
  set(value) {
    this[0] = value - 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr); // [1, 2]
arr[1] = 42;
console.log(arr); // [41, 42]
arr[0] = 27;
console.log(arr); // [27, 28]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

¹ "array index names" - Here's what [the spec says](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type) about property names that are array indexes:

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53</sup> - 1. An *array index* is an *integer index* whose numeric value *i* is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

Comment: This kinda makes me sad because it could've made making a dynamic array very simple and clean. Thank you.

Comment: @testy.potato - I'm not following you...? Arrays are already very dynamic in JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for well detailed answer :) you're awesome man.

Comment: @testy.potato - That said, provided you provide both a getter and a setter, I can't see any immediate problem with doing this... :-) Added an example of doing that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By dynamic I meant, for example, all the other values in an array changes according to the 1st value of that array. It would be easily possible to make it using function however you have to call it which ruins the ease of accessing it.

Comment: @testy.potato - Either this getter/setter approach or a proxy approach would work. If it doesn't really need to be an *array* (and arrays [aren't really arrays anyway](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), then I'd lean toward your own object/class you define and probably wrap a proxy around instances, implementing the `get` and `set` traps (at least). That way, you control what you want to happen when (say) you remove the 0th entry. Proxies are **very cool** and very powerful, but also a lot slower than normal objects (even those with getters/setters).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a setter/getter, you could use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) instead and evaluate the accessor and return different values.

```js
var handler = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
        return prop in obj
            ? obj[prop]
            : obj[0] + 1;
    }
};

var p = new Proxy([1], handler);

console.log(p[1]);
p.push(10)
console.log(p[1]);
console.log(p[2]);
```

Comment: Proxy is a cool function but I don't like the fact that I have to call the proxy when I need to change something in an array. I wanted to make a dynamic array where you change a value and others will change accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about a proxy, too. @testy.potato - You don't have to expose the array at all (in fact, Nina doesn't above, she only exposes the proxy), which effectively makes the proxy the array...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't have much experience with proxy TBH. But would it be possible to achieve in a complex array inside object (Tree like) structure?

Comment: @testy.potato, why not try it?